# Populate datas to List from another List in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have a List which stores data dynamically from database.

```
List<string> StoreData=new List<string>();
```

It stores data in the order given below

```
MonthNumber(1=jan,2=feb,3=mar etc),Categoryid(1,2,3),TotalPrice
```

For example it's value can be ,

```
 10,1,100
 9,2,200
 10,2,700
 8,3,600
 8,2,100
 8,1,500
```

Now I want to loop through this List and need to create another list , which should store data in below format.

```
8,100,500,600
9,0,200,0
10,100,700,0
```

That is,it should store data in ascending order of MonthNumber and Categoryid. No need to store the Categoryid. but the price order should be on Categoryid basis.

Comment: Why `9,0,200,0` instead of `9,200` or `9,0,0,200`?

Comment: Well, What you have tried so far? have you initiated your works?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre  StoreData list contains  9,2,200. where 2 is categoryid. There is no value for categoryid 1 and 3.so it should store as zero.    9,0,200,0

Comment: Well. It is not really best practice to store multiple values into one column. I think you should review you database storage

Comment: @user2431727 : And also for us to invest time into your question we would like to see what you have tried. Because SO it not a code writing service. Do you have problem with something specific?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your input is very weird, and if you had the option you should probably not have a list of strings that represent your data the way it does now.

Now in order to go from data in 1 format to another format, it's better to first parse the data and map it to a data structure that actually represents your data well, and then use this data structure to format it into any format you want.

Firstly, we're parsing all the data into a new `list`:

```
var parsedList = inputList.Select(i => { 
    var splittedAndParsed = i.Split(",").Select(int.parse);
    return splittedAndParsed;
});
```

After running this, `parsedList` will contain for each row of data a new `list` that holds the parsed integer value for each column of that row.

Now we want to store this data into a dictionary, so that we have all the prices and categories aggregated for the id. We will introduce a `class` in order to store the category and price data:

```
public class Price {
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Now we use this to create the `dictionary`:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<Price>>();
parsedList.ForEach(pl => {
     if(!dict.ContainsKey(pl[0], new List<Price>())) {
          dict.Add(pl[0]);
     }

     dict[pl[0]].Add(new Price { CategoryId = pl[1], Price = pl[2] });
});
```

Now we have `dict` that holds all your data in the way you can access it easily and format it any way you might like.

For instance you could do:

```
foreach(var kvp in dict) {
    var sorted = kvp.Value.Sort(p => p.Category);
    string write = $"{kvp.Key},;

    sorted.ForEach(s => write.Append($"{s},");

    Console.WriteLine(write);
}
```

This will not padd 0's when a list of categories does not have 3 columns, but you can just add those without too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a `Linq` only solution:

```
var result = StoreData.GroupBy(s => s.Split(',')[0])
    .Select(x => x.Key +"," + 
        string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(1,3)
            .Select(r => x.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Split(',')[1] == r + "") != null ? 
                x.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Split(',')[1] == r + "")
                .Split(',')[2] : "0")));
```

[Dotnet Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aSTLWC)